# Combining a two row result in to two columns (mysql)

Tags: mysql

This is **file_tbl**[image]
This is **name_tbl**[image]

I want the following result.
[image]

```
select email, file, name 
from file_tbl as ft 
join name_tble as nt on ft.email = nt.email 
where nt appId = 6
```

doesn't give the desired result.

How to achieve that?

Comment: http://rextester.com/LJZT12227 - basically you have to leverage group_concat function in mysql

Comment: This works but is there anyother way to get those values in two columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will be something that you can use:

```
SELECT email,GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT file SEPARATOR ','),
       name from file_tbl 
       as ft join name_tble 
       as nt on ft.email = nt.email 
WHERE 1 
GROUP BY nt.email
```

Comment: isn't there any other way to get this as two values